# pdf.js - Display pdf inaccessible for the client. Only accessible from back-end

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf

I want to display a pdf with [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/). But this pdf-file is not inside the same directory as my project so can only be accessed by calling my back-end file `getFile.php`, which returns the entire file as response.

This is how the tree on the server looks with relevant files (simplified):

```
~
|-- Mediadrop
|   |-- this_is_the_pdf_i_want.pdf
|   |-- ...
|-- Webpage
|   |-- **index.html/js/css files etc.**
|   |-- getFile.php
|   |-- build
|   |   |-- pdf.js
|   |-- web
|   |   |-- viewer.html
```

To access `this_is_the_pdf_i_want.pdf` I call `getFile.php` like this `href="file.php?id=16"` which runs the following code.

```
// getFile.php

$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT unique_id, container FROM media_files WHERE media_id = ?");

if (!$stmt) {
  error_log("prepare returned false");
  exit;
} else {
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
}

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($unique_id, $container);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

  $filename = "../mediadrop/" . $unique_id; // $unique_id == this_is_the_file_i_want.pdf
  $fp = fopen($filename, "r");

  // send the right headers
  header("Content-Type: application/" . $container);
  header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));

  // dump the video and stop the script
  fpassthru($fp);
}
```

This returns the response of the entire pdf file.

I cannot "combine" the `pdf.js` and `getFile.php` calls either, it would look like this:
`href="/web/viewer.html?file=file.php?id=16"` which is not valid html. And `pdf.js`wants the **filename** not the content directly. And I can't do `href="/web/viewer.html?file=../Mediadrop/this_is_the_pdf_i_want.pdf` because it's forbidden to access data outside the root folder.

---

I have tried this [renderPDF](https://gist.github.com/fcingolani/3300351) code.

With that code I can successfully output my PDF file onto a `<div>` but I want the full viewer (in a new window) with all the options provided with the default [viewer.html](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html). `renderPDF` just outputs the raw pdf to the div so to say.

I call `renderPDF` like this:

```
renderPDF('file.php?id=16', document.getElementById('pdf_holder'));
```

Maybe I can change some code inside the `renderPDF` code to pass the fetched PDF into `pdf.js`somehow.

Either that or make `renderPDF` also display all the options available from `viewer.html`

I don't really know where to go from here. Everything I've tried doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use encodeURIComponent() or php equivalent to encode file= param per https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#file

Comment: So simple. Thank you